# Where can I find column definitions for ed.gov data?

Tags: government, data.gov, education

Thanks to [Is there an open database of elementary, middle, and high schools in the United States?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/786/is-there-an-open-database-of-elementary-middle-and-high-schools-in-the-united) I found http://www.ed.gov/developers where I downloaded a list of schools ( School District / Local Education Agency (LEA) Listing ). However, I do not see where I can find a list of column definitions anywhere.

Where Can I find this information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you download the dataset directly off of http://www.ed.gov/developers ? If so, a lot of metadata and data discussion can be found in the PDF file linked to the right of the orange CSV, JSON, XML, and API links. Attaching a screenshot below.

**EDIT 1**: One more trick -- if you are using the API endpoint, switch `rows.json` in that URL to `columns.json` and you'll get some more information such as what the `name` of the column is as opposed to the lowercase/parameterized `fieldName` but the PDF should still have more information and explanation.

Does this help? If not, which data set are you referring to?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks! I wish they had made that a bit more obvious. One could believe that the PDF link is a PDF version of the data on that row, or maybe it is just me :-P