# Public School Teacher Dataset

Tags: data-request, usa, government, education

I'm looking for a dataset with information about public (and private, if possible) school teachers in the United States, including names, schools, and possibly any other identifying information such as department, school location, etc.

I assume that this information is freely available. I have tried the methods explained in this post: 
[Is there an open database of elementary, middle, and high schools in the United States?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/786/is-there-an-open-database-of-elementary-middle-and-high-schools-in-the-united)
but the farthest I was able to get was a dataset including every public school in the United States. If anyone has any information on such a dataset, or possibly a direct link to one, I would be grateful.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is a public record in every state I've ever worked.  You're likely to have to go state-by-state to collect it.  File a public records request with the state's department of education or equivalent.

However, many organizations have already done this.  For example here's a link to one for the state of Washington produced by the (Spokane) Spokesman-Review: http://data.spokesman.com/salaries/schools/2016/

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find one nationally, but it seems like you ought to dig in by state. For instance, there appears to be [school directory data for the state of Oregon](http://www.ode.state.or.us/search/results/?id=227), and in Portland, there also seems to be a list of [list of people working in it's public schools](https://www.pps.net/Page/2141). The first link appears to list it's staff in PDF files, but that's all I checked. Have you tried www.data.gov?